# Criando JAR com dependências em Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

Quero usar o **Maven** para gerar o JAR com suas dependências em formato `.jar`, as soluções que encontrei não são validas.

O **Eclipse** possui três formas de *gerar* um JAR executavel.

1. Extract required libraries into gerenated JAR
2. Package required libraries into generated JAR *< Utilizo essa no Eclipse.*
3. Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR

E o Maven possui uma forma equivalente ao Eclipse?

---

**Usando `maven-jar-plugin`**

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>qualquer.que.seja.seu.pacote.ClasseMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**Problema:** Esse modo gera um JAR sem as dependências em formato `.jar`.

---

**Usando `maven-assemply-plugin`**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>qualquer.que.seja.seu.pacote.ClasseMain</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Problema:** Gera um JAR com as dependências "extraídas" fora do formato `.jars`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe também o [**Maven Shade Plugin**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) que permite empacotar o artefato em um *super-jar*, incluindo suas dependências, e ainda renomear os pacotes de algumas dependências se você desejar.

Veja um exemplo:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>org.sonatype.haven.HavenCli</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Além de juntar tudo num único jar, o que o torna muito fácil de distribuir para download, por exemplo, o *Shade* também permite renomear pacotes de dependências, ajudando muito em casos onde pode haver conflitos de classpath, por exemplo.

É importante notar que os plugins ***shade*** e ***assembly*** não são concorrentes diretos, embora os dois permitam empacotar as dependências num jar. No quesito empacotamento, o assembly é mais poderoso, flexível e complicado. O shade possui menos funcionalidades, mas para criar um *uber-jar* ele é mais direto e simples.

Comment: Usei esse método e recebo `[ERROR] Could not find goal 'attached' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.2 among available goals shade, help -> [Help 1]` e outros. esto procurando soluções.

Comment: Erro corrigido. Estava usando `<goal>attached</goal>` troquei por `<goal>shade</goal>`.

Comment: @EduardoBentoRochaJunior Ok, já ia falar que estava mais parecendo com a outra resposta.

Comment: @utliuz, gostei desse `shade`, para cada compilação ele gera um JAR e mantei um antigo, é isso mesmo? Tem alguma forma de ter o `.jar` tipo `commons-net-3.3.jar`. Em todos os testes que fiz com Maven tenho o folder das minha dependências `org/apache/commons/..` acredito que vai funcionar da mesma forma, porém meu JAR ganha uns kB e mais. :D

Comment: @EduardoBentoRochaJunior Isso mesmo. Geralmente o novo super jar serve para distribuição e fica mais gordinho mesmo, já que inclui as dependências dentro dele. Dessa forma, você não precisa ter os jars na pasta. Mas, se você quiser ter as dependências em jars separados, então pode usar o outro plugin (**assembly**) para criar um zip com os jars, por exemplo.

Comment: +1 shade é o esquema pra empacotar JARzão fácil de rodar.

Answer (score 4):

Faltou você configurar como o `maven-assembly-plugin` será executado, ou seja, qual *goal* e em qual fase do maven também. Para empacotar um *jar* com as dependências durante a fase de *package*, a configuração fica assim:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>qualquer.que.seja.seu.pacote.ClasseMain</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attached</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Fiz esse teste, ele cria um JAR e a parte legal é que o JUNIT não está mais no meu `JAR`, porém as dependências continuam desempacotados em formato de folder, Obrigado

Comment: Ele não criou um jar `nome-do-projeto-jar-with-dependencies.jar`?

Comment: Criou, porém as dependências estão em formato folder (entende), o eclipse pega esse  `commons-net-3.3.jar` e coloca dentro do meu `.jar`, usando esse plugin ele cria um pasta chamada `org/apache/commons/..`. Entendeu?

Comment: Entendi Eduardo. Tentei aqui de todas as formas usar o `maven-assembly-plugin` para gerar com os jars e até consegui. Porém esbarrei em um [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-334) que não coloca o classpath no arquivo `MANIFEST.MF`. Daí o jar não fica executável.